# how to fix VAR does not exist in if-else and foreach clause

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

```
private void ChartConfig()
{    
    var qnb;                

    for (int o = 1601; o < 1612 + 1; o++)
    {
        if (o == 1601)
        {
            qnb = (from gog in db.SPerf_Notes
                   where gog.Module == ASPxComboBox1.Text.Trim()
                   select new { gog.Module, gog.KPI_Name, gog._1 }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            qnb = (from gog in db.SPerf_Notes
                   where gog.Module == ASPxComboBox1.Text.Trim()
                   select new { gog.Module, gog.KPI_Name, gog._11 }).ToList();
        }                

        foreach (var a in qnb)
        {
            list3.Add(a.Module.Trim());
            list3.Add(a.KPI_Name.Trim());
            list3.Add(a._1.ToString());
        }
 }
```

In top of page I initialized `var qnb;` but I think it does not work. 
Error is :

> Error 123 Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialize

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your `qnb` as follows

```
IEnumerable<object> qnb= Enumerable.Empty<object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx): "var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement"

When you use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, that variable is called "implicitly typed". That means that the compiler determines the type of the variable based on the value that you assigned to it.

A better way to handle this in your code would be like this:

```
private void ChartConfig()
{    
    for (int o = 1601; o < 1612 + 1; o++)
    {            
        var qnb = (from gog in db.SPerf_Notes
                   where gog.Module == ASPxComboBox1.Text.Trim()
                   select new { 
                        gog.Module, 
                        gog.KPI_Name, 
                        (o == 1601 ? gog._1 : gog._11) //You should give this field a name
                    }).ToList();

        foreach (var a in qnb)
        {
            list3.Add(a.Module.Trim());
            list3.Add(a.KPI_Name.Trim());
            list3.Add(a._1.ToString());
        }
 }
```